# How can I fit a shape in swift ui to accommodate the length and width of a text view

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image: This is what I want to happen in my code and I want the rectangle to scale to whatever font size.]

```
ZStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .scaledToFit() //.frame(width: 200, height: 25)
        
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "tag.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            
        Text("Tickets Not Available")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    }
}
.scaledToFit()
```

> As you can see my views are placed in a zstack so that the rounded rectangle can be the background of the text view. I've tried so many different things like where to put the .scaledtofit and it just gives me wack results each time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

is this what you're after (note the Image.resizable):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).foregroundColor(.blue)
        HStack{
            Image(systemName: "tag.fill").resizable().padding(4).foregroundColor(.white).scaledToFit()
            Text("Get Tickets").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }.fixedSize()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear but if you are trying to fit a shape inside the text view, and you are fine with getting rid of scaledToFit, then the code should be:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).foregroundColor(.red).frame(width: textView.width, height: textView.height)
```

Hope this helps, and hopefully you didn't need to use scaledToFit.
If you did tell me in comments.

Comment: No im using swift ui and that's not what I want, I would like the rectangle to scale to the size of the text like in the picture I attached.

Answer (score -1):

A reusable ButtonStyle might be helpful here. Instead of a `ZStack`, using the `.background` modifier helps to keep the size of the Button contents:

```swift
struct RoundedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            configuration.label
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).foregroundColor(Color.blue))
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```swift
Button(
    action: {
        print("Button Tapped")
    },
    label: {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "tag.fill")
            Text("Tickets")
        }
    }
)
.buttonStyle(RoundedButtonStyle())
```